# HealthKit - accumulate energy burned in watchOS 4

Tags: swift, watchkit, healthkit, watchos-4

In watchOS 3, when you wanted to accumulate energy burned, you could use something like:

```
totalEnergyBurned.addQuantities(from: samples, unit: HKUnit.calorie())
```

Now in WatchOS 4, HKUnit.calorie() is deprecated and has been replaced by `HKUnit.smallCalorie()` and `HKUnit.largeCalorie()`.

So, to measure the energy burned now, do we accumulate `smallCalorie()`, `largeCalorie()` or both?

Unfortunately the Apple documentation today is still in BETA and doesn't tell us much yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkunit/1615359-calorie), `HKUnit.calorie()` represents **gram calorie**. You should use `smallCalorie` (a.k.a. gram calorie) for the same purpose.

**`largeCalorie` = `smallCalorie` * 1000**